# .htaccess newbie issue using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create SEO-friendly urls for my site. I found out I can use `.htaccess` to rewrite them. So I tried this:

```
> http://www.domain.com/page/1/mypage
> http://www.domain.com/user/2/myuser
> http://www.domain.com/help/3/myhelp
```

Now I am stuck with a common rule and I don't understand Ant to redirect traffic based on the name of the page:

I use:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?page=$1
```

Then in my PHP I don't get the page correctly, I get the file which is wrong.

How can I fix this?

Comment: For a good start, check this online tool http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php to see how your URLs can be managed. It will generate you .htaccess code as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z_\-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z_\-]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [NC,L]
```

**NC** (or nocase) Makes the test case-insensitive, A = a;

**L** (or last) Last rule. Stop the rewriting process here and don't apply any more rewrite rules;

You can get more info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: i see the difference, let me try, why nc and l?

Comment: `NC` is *no case*, ie case insensitive. `L` is *last*, meaning rule processing will stop if this rule matches